# Get an image from web with authentication

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, nsurl

In my iOS app I need to load an image from web, but this image is on a server in which it's necessary to give username and password. I tried to use this code:

```
 - (void) loadImageFromWeb:(NSString *)urlImg {
    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlImg];
    NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];


    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * response,
                                               NSData * data,
                                               NSError * error) {
                               if (!error){
                                   UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
                                   [self.imageObjectScanned setImage:image];
                               } else {
                                   NSLog(@"ERRORE: %@", error);
                               }

                           }];
}
```

But it return an error and says that:

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1012 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1012.)" UserInfo=0x14e6b420 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://54.204.6.246/magento8/media/catalog/product/cache/0/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/s/c/scheda_non_shop.jpg, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://54.204.6.246/magento8/media/catalog/product/cache/0/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/s/c/scheda_non_shop.jpg, NSUnderlyingError=0x14e695c0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error -1012.)"}
```

I guess this error it's because I'm not sending the username and the password. How I can send username and password to load this image?

Comment: You can check `NSURLCredential`

Comment: Check this link https://discussions.apple.com/message/22935979#22935979

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the basic authentication in header of your request object.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

NSString *authCredentials = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", userName, password];
NSString *authValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@",[authCredentials base64EncodedStringWithWrapWidth:0]];
[urlRequest setValue:authValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * response,
                                           NSData * data,
                                           NSError * error) {
                           if (!error){
                               UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
                               [self.imageObjectScanned setImage:image];
                           } else {
                               NSLog(@"ERRORE: %@", error);
                           }

                       }];
```

Download the Base64.h/.m files from [here](https://github.com/nicklockwood/Base64/tree/master/Base64) and import it into your project.
Add header #import "Base64.h" in your implementation file.

Comment: I'm trying your solution, but when I insert the code you paste here, Xcode doesn't recognize the method `base64EncodedStringWithOptions`, what I should import to work with this method? In my class I'm adding the category `NSData+Base64`

Comment: @lucgian841 I have edited the answer for Base64.h/.m files and update the conversion method.

Comment: You can use below base64 encoding method if you are using iOS7. 

- (NSString *)base64EncodedStringWithOptions:(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions)options;

Answer (score 0):

You may try to pass the credentials within the URL as a query component, as described in the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLConnection/sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:):

> If authentication is required in order to download the request, the required credentials must be specified as part of the URL. If authentication fails, or credentials are missing, the connection will attempt to continue without credentials.

The parameters which comprises the query component need to be properly encoded. You may use this method to encode the parameters for a URL shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19855735/how-to-send-multiple-parameterts-to-php-server-in-http-post/19857449#19857449).

For example:

```
NSDictionary* parameters = @{@"login": name, @"password": password};
NSData* queryComponent = [parameters dataFormURLEncoded];
NSString* queryComponentString = [NSString alloc] initWithData:queryComponent
                                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString* urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?%@", 
                                   urlImg, queryComponentString];    
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString: urlString];
```

A small caveat:

The described method which encodes the parameter included in the query component for a URL follows strictly the suggested algorithm specified by w3c: [The application/x-www-form-urlencoded encoding algorithm](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#application/x-www-form-urlencoded-encoding-algorithm) which should be applied for URLs.

This encoding algorithm will escape a tilde character `~` when it occurs in either the name or value string. However, according the more *general* rules to compose a URL ([see RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986)), the tilde character should not be escaped. I don't think this will ever be a problem, though.

Answer (score 0):

This GitHub-issue suggests that your server is using an incorrect SSL certificate:
https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/issues/1511

But if it is a credentials-issue, I suggest looking at NSURLCredential
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSURLCredential_Class/Reference/Reference.html

You can present the credentials in a delegate method to NSURLConnection, or store them once and let them be used for all requests.

Alternatively, you could take a look into using RestKit.