# POST Request with NSDictionary

Tags: php, html, ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

Hi Guys :D Please explain to me how I should use in your class NSDictionary (on this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19855735/how-to-send-multiple-parameterts-to-php-server-in-http-post/19857449#19857449)).What i should say `request.HTTPBody = [param dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; that my program work correctly?`

This my code

```
#import "MainClass.h"

@implementation MainClass

- (IBAction)actionButton:(id)sender {

NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL
                                                                    URLWithString:@"https://login.dnevnik.ru"]
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:15.0];


request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
NSString *username = _loginLogin.text;
NSString *password= _passwordLogin.text;
GlobalUserName = username;
GlobalPassword = password;
NSDictionary *param = @{@"Username": GlobalUserName,@"password": GlobalPassword};



/*NSUserDefaults *loginData = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *username1 = [loginData objectForKey:@"username"] ;
NSString *password1 = [loginData objectForKey:@"password"];*/


//Параметры посылаемого запроса
request.HTTPBody = [param dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"
forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];


NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];


if (connection) {
    _otvet.text = @"Соединение установлено";
    NSLog(@"ama ama");

}
else
{
    _otvet.text=@"Проблема с соединением";
    NSLog(@"ama ama faza");
}

}

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse 
*)response    
{
[receivedData setLength:0];

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{

[receivedData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                           initWithTitle:@"Ошибка" message:@"Пожалуйста, проверьте
соединение с Интернетом." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[errorAlert show];          
}


- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

NSString * data = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:receivedData    
encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

if ([data   isEqualToString: @"OK"]) {

    _otvet.text = @"Вы успешно залогинены.";
    NSLog(@"Вы успешно залогинены.");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Ошибка авторизации %@,%@",GlobalUserName,GlobalPassword);
}
}
```

In my case xcode when compiling says

> No visible @interface for 'NSDictionary' declares the selector
>   'dataUsingEncoding:'

Comment: I know this is old. But hopefully you can respond. What did you define GlobalUserName, and GlobalPassword as in your Mainclass.h

Answer (score 2):

You should pass NSString as a BODY.

Do this:

```
NSString *postString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Username=%@&password=%@",username,password];
request.HTTPBody = [postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Or if you want encode NSDictionary to JSON String and decode it on backend - better way to do that, but more work :)

```
request.HTTPBody = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:param options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error]
```

Comment: Should as in.. Cannot pass nsdictionary? Because I am having an issue passing NSDictionary to the php script... NSStrings work but not NSDictionary

Comment: you can, just use: request.HTTPBody = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionary options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil]