# NSUrlConnection, http-post and session

Tags: ios, objective-c, https, http-post, nsurlconnection

I have a question about NSUrlConnection and http session.
I need to call an httpS url using a POST. 
I tried this code:

```
NSString *bodyData = @"selectTipoVeicolo=A&inputTarga=EN784DC";
NSMutableURLRequest *postRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.theUrl.com"]];


[postRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    // Designate the request a POST request and specify its body data
    [postRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [postRequest setHTTPBody:[NSData dataWithBytes:[bodyData UTF8String] length:strlen([bodyData UTF8String])]];

    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:postRequest
                                                                  delegate:self];

    [connection start];
```

but I obtain an html page with this message:

> Your session has timed out. Web applications store information about
>   what you are doing on the server. This information is called the
>   session.
>
> Web servers must track many, many sessions. If you are inactive for a
>   long enough time (usually, a few minutes), this information is
>   discarded to make room for active users.
>
> At this point you may restart the session to continue.

**EDIT**

Server Response:

`<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x8ad8400> { URL: theHost.com/http://voas.theHost.com:7777/… } { status code: 200, headers { "Cache-Control" = private; Connection = "Keep-Alive"; "Content-Length" = 2383; "Content-Type" = "text/html;charset=UTF-8"; Date = "Wed, 04 Dec 2013 21:21:52 GMT"; "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=50,max=9"; Server = "Oracle-Application-Server-10g/9.0.4.3.0 Oracle-HTTP-Server OracleAS-Web-Cache-10g/9.0.4.3.0 (N)"; "Set-Cookie" = "text cookie"; } }`

How can I avoid this problem? What I need?

Answer (score 1):

You can examine what the server returns in the header by also capturing the response:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
     _data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    _response = (NSHTTPURLResponse*) response;
}
```

You can examine the response variable here or in `connectionDidFinishLoading`. This should give you a clue about the missing parts. As it stands it could be a server issue and it is not clear what the client is expected to send.

BTW, no need to start the connection. The init method already starts it. From the docs:

> Returns an initialized URL connection and begins to load the data for the URL request.

Comment: Hi Mundi, I printed my response:

<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x8ad8400> { URL: https://www.theHost.com/http://voas.theHost.com:7777/param1,fromParam2.sdirect } { status code: 200, headers {
    "Cache-Control" = private;
    Connection = "Keep-Alive";
    "Content-Length" = 2383;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html;charset=UTF-8";
    Date = "Wed, 04 Dec 2013 21:21:52 GMT";
    "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=50,max=9";
    Server = "Oracle-Application-Server-10g/9.0.4.3.0 Oracle-HTTP-Server OracleAS-Web-Cache-10g/9.0.4.3.0 (N)";
    "Set-Cookie" = "text cookie";
} }

Answer (score 0):

There are at a least three issues: one error, one possible improvement and one potential issue:

1. The `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` MIME type does not have parameters. 
   (I'm wondering where this comes from)

   ```
   [postRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded charset=utf-8" 
      forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
   ```

   The `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` MIME type does not have parameters at all: you cannot specify a charset parameter. And if, parameters must be separated by a semi colon `;`.

   So, try:

   ```
   [postRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" 
      forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
   ```
2. When setting the body length, you need to set the length in bytes:

   This is your code:

   ```
   [postRequest setHTTPBody:[NSData dataWithBytes:[bodyData UTF8String] 
                     length:strlen([bodyData UTF8String])]];
   ```

   That can be written more efficiently:

   ```
   NSString* encodedString = ...; // ensure proper encoding!
   NSData* postData = [encodedString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
   ```
3. You need to ensure your body is properly encoded according the Content-Type.

   Currently, your data equals:

   ```
   @"selectTipoVeicolo=A&inputTarga=EN784DC"
   ```

   This *is* properly encoded. But encoding correctly by hand is error prone. I would suggest to implement a helper method for this. See here: [How to send multiple parameterts to PHP server in HTTP post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19855735/how-to-send-multiple-parameterts-to-php-server-in-http-post/19857449#19857449)

Comment: Hi CouchDeveloper,thanks for your suggestions...I would like to replicate a html form of a website...Is there a specific way to make this?

Comment: My question is: if I send a single request...why I obtain a "session timed out"?

Comment: According your edit, you didn't get a timeout. A "session timeout" is not part of the HTTP protocol, but an application thing. A HTTP session will be terminated by the application when it remains idle beyond a specified period of time. An application would then delete any state associated to a "session". Usually, a client needs to login again. HTTP status codes may differ, 401, 403 or a custom one, not specified in RFC 2616.