# Creating a Post Request in iOS

Tags: ios, post, nsurlconnection, nsurlconnectiondelegate

To begin with, I have looked up how to make a post request and have read multiple thread and docs about how to create one, however my data doesn't seem to be working.
I have two fields say x and html that i want to make to the call callname.
The GET form of this would be www.someserver.com/callname?x=something&y=something
Here is what my POST code looks like so far:

```
NSString *baseURLString = @"http://www.someserver.com/callname"
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[[NSURL URLWithString:baseURLString] standardizedURL]];
NSString *fields = [NSString stringWIthFormat:@"x=%@&html=%@",x,htmlSource];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:[NSData dataWithBytes:[fields UTF8String] length:strlen([fields UTF8String])]];

NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

The NSURLConnection Delegate Methods implemented as such

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{
    NSLog(@"Data Received");
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{ 
    NSLog(@"Error: %@" , error);
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
    NSLog(@"Connection Finished");
}
```

Did i miss something? My code looks pretty identical to most of the examples I found aside from the choice of encoding. Does it matter that I am passing in html source code as the value of y? Any tips or hints will be appreciated. I am very new to iOS and html handling in general so excuse my lack of knowledge on the subject. Thanks for your time!

Comment: I'm extremely curious where you did get this: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8"`

Comment: I fear, you even need to read more about how to properly percent encode the parameter list within an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You must implement the delegate protocol for `NSURLConnection` to get the response. You haven't posted any of that code, so I would assume this means you didn't implement the relevant methods.

Comment: Do i need to implement that delegate for the call to be successful? or is it to see what response i get from the server

Comment: You shouldn't need to implement it for the call to succeed, but you would need to implement it to know if it succeeded or not, and to see what response you got. So you would almost always want to implement it.

Comment: You can simplify things however if you use a third party library such as AFNetworking for your requests. Then you can use a block syntax for callbacks, instead of implementing delegate methods and such.

Comment: I implemented the methods and got a connection finished message back. No data received or error msg

Comment: Did you implement the delegate methods for receiving data?

Comment: Ah, I see that you had edited your question to show them. Well, maybe it isn't sending any data back at all for some reason. Try using something like the POSTMAN Chrome plugin to do your POST request and see if it gets anything back in response.

Comment: Well I made the call inside the app and it worked lol. But that still leaves me wondering why my call doesnt work. Did i setup the key value things wrong? Does it matter that i am passing straight html source code into the html=%@ parameter?

Comment: That could be it. You would need the HTML to be escaped to be handled correctly.

Answer (score 0):

One potential issue is that you missed to properly percent encode the parameters:

When using parameters like in your code with a content type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, I would suggest to create your parameters as (unencoded) `NSString` key/value pairs, create a `NSDictionary` object and use the following helper method described in the answer here ([How to send multiple parameterts to PHP server in HTTP post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19855735/how-to-send-multiple-parameterts-to-php-server-in-http-post/19857449#19857449)) which creates a properly encoded parameter string which you can add to the body.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your form URL encoded is not correct. I believe the solution is the following

```
[serviceRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

If you want to UTF-8 encode your values, you need to do it before, like for example,

```
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [_xmlDoc length]]; //Calculating the Content Length
    NSData *postData = [_xmlDoc dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; // preparing XML to be sent in POST
```

Notice you encode the string of POST data ahead of time.

Hope that this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

```
class Requests {

    class func loginRequest(userName:String, password:String, completion: @escaping ((JSON?, String?) -> ()) )
    {
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "your URL")!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
          //parameters
        let postString = "user_login=\(userName)&user_pass=\(password)"
        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { 
            data, response, error in guard error == nil else {
                print(error!)
                completion(nil, error!.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            guard let data = data else {
                completion(nil, "location not found")
                return
            }
            let jsonData = JSON(data)
            completion(jsonData, nil)
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code works for me. Did you remember to run `[connection start];` ?

Comment: Do i need to call that directly? I have a if(connection) NSLog("Connection Successful"); And I see the message. Do they mean different things? I also get the connection finished message from the delegate

Comment: `if(connection)` confirms only that you created the object successfully. To actually fire the connection you need to call the `start` method. To confirm the connection you should use the `NSURLConnectionDelegate` methods.

Comment: It's unlikely that the OPs code is the same as yours. What matters whether the code "works" (as expected) depends on the parameters _x_ and _htmlSource_, in particular whether they are properly percent encoded. Additionally, the OP used an init method which _immediately_ starts the connection, that is no `start` is required.