# Sending HTTP POST JSON parameter to PHP page - iOS

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, json

So I'm trying to send a parameter via POST to a php server and that parameter value must be a JSON value. The name of the parameter have to be 'data'

I mean, with get method that will be something like http:url.com/url/something.php?data={"jsonkey1":1,"jsonkey2":[.... or something like that

This is the code i have for now, but I can't get it to work. I prefer not to use external libraries but to use native methods.

```
// Writing JSON...
NSNumber *imagesCount = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:0];
NSMutableArray *arrayList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; // That's an empty array
//[arrayList addObject:@"image1.png"]; [arrayList addObject:@"image2.png"];
NSDictionary *dictionaryJSON = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:imagesCount, @"count",arrayList,@"list", nil];

NSString *param = @"data=";
NSMutableData *dataJSON = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
[dataJSON appendData:[param dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSError *error = nil;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionaryJSON options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];;
[dataJSON appendData:jsonData];

NSString* jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[jsonData bytes] length:[jsonData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"jsonData as string:\n%@, %@", jsonString, error);

jsonString = [jsonString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

// Request to server
NSString *url =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://url.com/ios/api/get_images_cache.php?"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", [dataJSON length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];


NSString* jsonStringdat = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[dataJSON bytes] length:[dataJSON length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
jsonStringdat=[jsonStringdat stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    jsonStringdat=[jsonStringdat stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
NSLog(@"Final jsonData as string:\n%@, %@", jsonStringdat, error);
//[request setValue:jsonStringdat forHTTPHeaderField:@"data"];
//[request setValue:jsonData forKey:@"data"];
[request setHTTPBody: [jsonStringdat dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Thank you for helping.

**EDIT:**

I finally did it, the problem was with these two lines:

```
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
```

I removed them and finally i get it to work, Thanks anyway !

Answer (score 0):

```
NSURLConnection* connection = [NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
```

Add that to the end, and then you need to make your class conform to the  and it can then know when the request has been completed successfully and when it failed with errors etc. Also, the way I constructed my requests in my App was:

```
NSMutableURLRequest* request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setTimeoutInterval:10];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

[request setHTTPBody:postData];
```

I hope that helps!

Edit:
Also, convert the JSON you have to a string before sending. This is how I did it:

```
NSData *dataFromJSON = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonObjects options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataFromJSON encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: I already made the connection, but the server response is not what I expected to be, I simply didn't put it because that part of the code worked well.
I also tried converting JSON to NSSTRING before sending with no results. Thanks for the fast reply anyway !

Comment: Have you tried sending a dummy string to the server? Just to see if you get a response?

Answer (score 0):

Here your expected answer

First coding part is ONLY for POSTING DATA IN TO SERVRE

```
//Here YOUR URL
   NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://url.com/ios/api/get_images_cache.php?"]];


//create the Method "GET" or "POST"
   [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

//Pass The String to server(YOU SHOULD GIVE YOUR PARAMETERS INSTEAD OF MY PARAMETERS)
  NSString *userUpdate =[NSString strin gWithFormat:@"user_email=%@&user_login=%@&user_pass=%@&  last_upd_by=%@&user_registered=%@&",txtemail.text,txtuser1.text,txtpass1.text,txtuser1.text,datestr,nil];



//Check The Value what we passed
  NSLog(@"the data Details is =%@", userUpdate);

//Convert the String to Data
  NSData *data1 = [userUpdate dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

//Apply the data to the body
  [request setHTTPBody:data1];

//Create the response and Error
  NSError *err;
  NSURLResponse *response;

  NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];

  NSString *resSrt = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:responseData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

//This is for Response
  NSLog(@"got response==%@", resSrt);
 if(resSrt)
 {
   NSLog(@"got response");
   /* ViewController *view =[[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:NULL];
   [self presentViewController:view animated:YES completion:nil];*/
 }
 else
 {
   NSLog(@"faield to connect");
 }
```

Second Part is for  GETTING RESPONSE THROUGH JSON

```
    //just give your URL instead of my URL

        NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL  URLWithString:@"http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v1/search.ashx?query=London&num_of_results=3&format=json&key=xkq544hkar4m69qujdgujn7w"]];

       [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

       [request setValue:@"application/json;charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];

        NSError *err;

        NSURLResponse *response;

        NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request   returningResponse:&response error:&err];

      //Converting data to String for seeing response
        NSString *resSrt = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:responseData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

      //This is for Response
        NSLog(@"got response==%@", resSrt);

      //You need to check response.Once you get the response copy that and paste in ONLINE JSON VIEWER.If you do this clearly you can get the correct results.    

      //After that it depends upon the json format whether it is DICTIONARY or ARRAY 

        NSDictionary *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &err];

        NSArray *array=[[jsonArray objectForKey:@"search_api"]objectForKey:@"result"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` in a POST request where you can send a number of parameters (key/value pairs).

Notice though that the parameter keys and values must be properly encoded. In particular, a JSON usually contains a number of characters which cannot be used as a parameter-value as is.

Thus, given an object which represents your JSON, *jsonRep*, which is either an `NSArray` or a `NSDictionary` object, you get the JSON:

```
NSError* error;
NSData* json = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonRep 
                                               options:0 
                                                 error:&error];
```

Now, you need to *encode* the json. The encoding algorithm required is defined here:
[The application/x-www-form-urlencoded encoding algorithm](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#application/x-www-form-urlencoded-encoding-algorithm)

And here is a Category for `NSDictionary` implementing method `dataFormURLEncoded` which returns a `NSData` object representing the encoded parameters which are given as a `NSDictionary` (shown in another SO answer):[How to send multiple parameterts to PHP server in HTTP post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19855735/how-to-send-multiple-parameterts-to-php-server-in-http-post/19857449#19857449), e.g.:

```
NSData* paramsData = [@{@"key": @"value"} dataFormURLEncoded];
```

The "Parameter Dictionary" is required to have `NSString`s as keys and values. Thus we need to convert the JSON (as `NSData`) into a `NSString` (we know its encoding is UTF-8):

```
NSString* jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:json 
                                             encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Now we can create the "Parameter Dictionary:"

```
NSDictionary* paramsDict = @{@"data": jsonString};
```

Given, there is the `NSDictionary` Category shown in the linked SO answer, we get the parameters as an `NSData` object, properly encoded:

```
NSData* paramsData = [paramsDict dataFormURLEncoded];
```

The remaining part is just creating a POST request, and this is straight forward:

```
NSMutableURLRequest* request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL: url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", [paramsData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody: paramsData];
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code for POST and GET

```
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://url.com/ios/api/get_images_cache.php?"]];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    //Here GIVE YOUR PARAMETERS instead of my PARAMETER
    NSString *userUpdate =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"email_id=%@&pass=%@",txtEmail.text,txtPass.text,nil];

    NSData *data1 = [userUpdate dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    [request setHTTPBody:data1];

    NSError *err;
    NSURLResponse *response;

    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];

    NSString *resultStr=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:responseData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"resultstr==%@",resultStr);

    //You need to check response.Once you get the response copy that and paste in ONLINE JSON VIEWER.If you do this clearly you can get the correct results.    

    //After that it depends upon the json format whether it is DICTIONARY or ARRAY 

    NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
    NSString *equalilstr=[dict objectForKey:@"message"];
```